# How is Pact licensed?

Tags: pact

I'm looking all through the pact.io site and I can't seem to find anything about licensing.

What type of license does Pact/Pack Broker service use? Apache? MIT? GPL?

Maybe I'm dense but I cannot seem to find any licensing information on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nowhere on the website, but it's very easy to find on the github. https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact.io/blob/documentation/LICENSE

TLDR: It's MIT licensed.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @sgillen's answer (which for the Broker is correct).

Each Pact language implementation *may* have their own license depending on who authored it in the first place. In most cases, it's MIT, but [Pact JVM](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm) for example is Apache 2.0.

Each GitHub repository will have the license information there - it is the definitive source of truth.